# kendo ui cancel treeview drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, treeview, kendo-ui

i have a TreeView that once the user drops the item to the desired position, it displays a dialog box and asks for confirmation, if the user selects cancel, how would i also cancel the placement of the item so it goes back to its original position? my current code is below but isnt working:

```
var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));

newDiv.html('Are you sure you want to move the item: ' + title);
newDiv.dialog( {
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");

            e.setValid = false;

        }
    }
});
```

I have also tried doing the same kind of code on the dragend event and using `e.preventDefault();` with no more luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `drop` event handler provides the `setValid` function, which can prevent the drop from occurring. For example:

```
function onDrop(e) {
    e.setValid(confirm('Do you wish to move this item here?'));
}

$("#treeView").kendoTreeView({
    // ...
    dragAndDrop: true,
    drop: onDrop
});
```

I've written a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbristowe/q97MF/) which demonstrates how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the **drop** event and call prevent default there if the condition is not satisfied?