# Drag & Drop Issue Kendo UI Web TreeView In ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I have an issue in kendo treeView. I am doing validation in kendo treeview when the user drags and drop a node by using dragstart, dragend, drop events.

Issue is, I need to maintain unique node names in every level. when user drop a node then I am  checking the selected node with the destination node details by using following function-

var destNode = this.dataItem(e.destinationNode);

if the user moves the node one level up then e.destinationNode giving the neighbhour node details based on the I not able to maintain uniqueness. This  is the issue.

Is there any property to disable move option, I should continue only drag and drop.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can `e.preventDefault` inside the `drop` event if your condition is not satisfied when you want to cancel the drop. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995029/kendo-ui-cancel-treeview-drop)